# auto copy the newly added records to another mysql

Tags: mysql, local

i'm working on a local MySQL that installed on windows 7 in my company we are using ms access for the data entry .. we add new data every hour
and also we have a website that's connected to a public MySQL server "via web application" for clients .. and one of my tasks to copy all the database from the local MySQL server to the public one "to be shown for our clients".. so my question is there's any way to "auto" copy the new entered data from my local MySQL server to the public one ?
OR like when we add new record it goes to 2 different MySQL servers in same time?

i'm forced to do it that way because i cant figure out how to directly connect the website with the local MySQL machine

sorry the question might sounds stupid but i don't have much knowledge in this field .. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There many different ways to do that.

1) you can use a MySQL replication, so MySQL copy all inserts and
   updates to your Slave Database (public Server). Also it synced
   automaticl when the Connection dropped to the public server.

2) you can use a very good tool "percona toolkit". there is a toll
   that synced tables or schemas to a other Database.

3) You can use a Proxy like MaxScale from MariaDB. They can split Querys
   like insert or update and send it to 2 differnt servers.

Comment: i read a lil about MySQL replication but i feel like there's alot of missing info's for me .. we have 2 MySQL machines .. the local machine "master" and the public one "slave" but i only have the access to the second one since the server is in the internet so i cant use those commands in it .. so can u please tell me the steps of any of these methods or point out a website that have it .. ty for reply

Comment: If you want to use the replication the Slave Server (public server), that is the Server where the data to transfer, must can reach the Master server in your office. You can do this via a VPN connection between your 2 Sites.
The you dump the Master Database to save the data and then import this dump in the slave.
at last you must configure your Slave and start the Replication.

Comment: Here ist a link to a very good site where is a step for step sample
https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/setting-up-replication/

Comment: ty alot for ur help !!

Comment: for example i have no privileges of configure anything only show commands .. i couldn't find other way